# Matlab get all possible combinations less than a value

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix as follows:

```
id      value
=============
 1       0.5
 2       0.5
 3       0.8
 4       0.3
 5       0.2
```

From this array, I wish to find all the possible combinations that have a sum less than or equal to 1. That is,

```
result
======
1 2
1 4 5
2 4 5
3 5
1 5
1 4
2 4
2 5
...
```

In order to get the above result, my idea has been to initially compute all the possibilities of finding sum of elements in the array, like so:

```
for ii = 1 : length(a) % compute number of possibilities 
     no_of_possibilities = no_of_possibilities + nchoosek(length(a),ii);
end
```

Once this is done, then loop through all possible combinations.
I would like to know if there's an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Your code is not complete, see [mcve]. I think using a for loop is the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = [0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.2];
required = cell(1, length(data));
subsets = cell(1, length(data));
for k = 2:length(data)-1 % removes trivial cases (all numbers or one number at a time)
    % generate all possible k-pairs (if k = 3, then all possible triplets
    % will be generated)
    combination = nchoosek(1:length(data), k);
    % for every triplet generated, this function sums the corresponding
    % values and then decides whether then sum is less than equal to 1 or
    % not
    findRequired = @(x) sum(data(1, combination(x, :))) <= 1;
    % generate a logical vector for all possible combinations like [0 1 0]
    % which denotes that the 2nd combination satisfies the condition while
    % the others do not
    required{k} = arrayfun(findRequired, 1:size(combination, 1));
    % access the corresponding combinations from the entire set
    subsets{k} = combination(required{k}, :);
end
```

This produces the following subsets:

```
1     2
1     4
1     5
2     4
2     5
3     5
4     5
1     4     5
2     4     5
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not in easy way, however is a faster way, as I removed the combination which its subsets are not passed the condition.

```
bitNo = length(A);         % number of bits
setNo = 2 ^ bitNo - 1;     % number of sets
subsets = logical(dec2bin(0:setNo, bitNo) - '0'); % all subsets
subsets = subsets(2:end,:); % all subsets minus empty set!
subsetCounter = 1;
resultCounter = 1;
result = {};
while(1)
    if( subsetCounter >= size(subsets,1))
         break;
    end
    if(sum(A(subsets(subsetCounter,:).',2)) <= 1)
         result{resultCounter} = A(subsets(subsetCounter,:).',1).';
         resultCounter = resultCounter + 1;
         subsetCounter = subsetCounter + 1;
    else
         % remove all bad cases related to the current subset
         subsets = subsets(sum((subsets & subsets(subsetCounter,:)) - subsets(subsetCounter,:),2) ~= 0,:);
    end       
end
```

Generate the subsets using this [method](http://matlabtricks.com/post-7/select-all-subsets-of-a-set). After that, check the condition for each subset. If the subset does not pass the condition, all its supersets are removed from the subsets. To do this, using `sum((subsets & subsets(i,:)) - subsets(i,:),2) ~= 0` which mean get some rows from `subsets` which has not the same elements of the not passed subset. By doing this, we able to not to consider some bad cases anymore. Although, theoretically, this code is **Θ(2^n)**.

Comment: @SardarUsama preallocation for what? for `result` we can't.  as we don't know about the size of the result.

Comment: Here it can be awful! as the number of subsets are exponential, although the result would be linear!

Answer (score 0):

Here is potential solution, using inefficient steps, but borrowing efficient code from various SO answers. Credit goes to those original peeps.

```
data = [0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.2];
```

First get all combinations of indices, not necessarily using all values.

```
combs = bsxfun(@minus, nchoosek(1:numel(data)+numel(data)-1,numel(data)), 0:numel(data)-1);
```

Then get rid of repeated indices in each combination, regardless of index order

```
[ii, ~, vv] = find(sort(combs,2));
uniq = accumarray(ii(:), vv(:), [], @(x){unique(x.')});
```

Next get unique combinations, regardless of index order... NOTE: You can do this step much more efficiently by restructuring the steps, but it'll do.

```
B = cellfun(@mat2str,uniq,'uniformoutput',false);
[~,ia] = unique(B);
uniq=uniq(ia);
```

Now sum all values in `data` based on cell array (`uniq`) of index combinations

```
idx = cumsum(cellfun('length', uniq));
x = diff(bsxfun(@ge, [0; idx(:)], 1:max(idx)));
x = sum(bsxfun(@times, x', 1:numel(uniq)), 2);  %'// Produce subscripts
y = data([uniq{:}]);                               % // Obtain values
sums_data = accumarray(x, y);
```

And finally only keep the index combinations that sum to <= 1

```
allCombLessThanVal = uniq(sums_data<=1)
```